# After ICS, Touch screen is not working when mobile is overheated

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, touchscreen, system-freeze, sony-xperia-mini-pro

I have Sony Xperia Mini pro, i recently updated it to ICS. But now when the phone is overheated (especially during recharging). The touch screen becomes unresponsive, even if i restart my phone, it stills that way.

It goes back to normal by itself after some period of time.

What should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Here's some more [info](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1387605). In short: the touch sensors are too sensitive and trigger by themselves when the phone is hot. I found that updating to newer Sony firmware does a recalibration, best have your phone a little overheated when you upgrade and the recalibration is OK afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Your touch screen needs to replace now. Please contact nearest Sony Service Centre.

Comment: CPU can also be an issue...

Comment: @SachinShekhar That is a known issue with some Xperia Mini's - and is acknowledged. The answer given by chancal1987 is the correct answer.